# c malloc changes char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc<2){
        printf("No file to read specified\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE *fileToRead=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if(fileToRead==NULL){
        printf("File couldn't be opened! Are you sure it exists and you have the permissions to read?\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *lineRead=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    char *search=" ";

    while((lineRead=readLine(fileToRead))!=NULL){
        if(lineRead[0]=='#'){
            printf("Comment at: %s\n",lineRead);
        }else if(lineRead[0]=='\0'){                
            printf("Comment at: %s\n",lineRead);

        } else {
            printf("linebef: %s  ",lineRead);
            char *command,*args,*tmpArg;
            command=strtok(lineRead,search);

            args=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(lineRead)));
            args[0]='\0';   

            while((tmpArg=strtok(NULL,search))!=NULL){
                args=strcat(args,tmpArg);
                args=strcat(args," ");
            }

            printf("line: %s, comm: %s, args: %s\n",lineRead,command,args);
            free(args);
            //TODO execv
        }

    }
    free(lineRead);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

this is my main program. it opens a file and reads it line by line. if there is a # or a blank space in the beginnig of the line the program continues to the next line. if not i want to parse my line according to " " spaces. the purpose of this program is to execute the lines of a programm in the command line. 
The problem is when i use malloc at args it somehow manipulates my lineRead variable and it then points to a wrong value. the first string before the first " " gets deleted somehow(  i think the pointer just is increased?).

```
# This is a comment followed by an empty line

/usr/bin/whoami
/bin/echo hello world
/bin/false
/usr/bin/id &
/bin/date
```

this is an example file that i have.
Does anyone see my problem here?

Here my output:

```
    Comment at: # This is a comment followed by an empty line
    Comment at:
    linebef: /usr/bin/whoami  line: , comm: , args:
    linebef: /bin/echo hello world  line: /bin/echo, comm: /bin/echo, args: hello world
    linebef: /bin/false  line: /bin/false, comm: /bin/false, args:
    linebef: /usr/bin/id &  line: /usr/bin/id, comm: /usr/bin/id, args: &
    linebef: /bin/date  line: /bin/date, comm: /bin/date, args:
```

Comment: You got some kind of stack or heap overwriting issue. Try checking your bounds.

Comment: Note that `args=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(lineRead)))` does not allocate space for the final NUL byte (if the intent is to also store a full line).

Comment: i added the output i am getting. the problem is that my readLine is suddenly the same as command and i don't understand why

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: `strtok` will modify the string you pass in to tokenize (in this case the string pointed to by lineRead), if that's your question.

Comment: Thank Joachim that was the solution to my problem. And thank you all other guys for helping me. I really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with:

```
while((lineRead=readLine(fileToRead))!=NULL){
    ...
```

lineRead is assigned to new value returned by readLine. Check your readLine function to see how data is returned. The common implementation of readLine should be:

```
char * readLine(FILE *fileToRead, char *lineRead) {
    // Read data into lineRead
    // if read failed, returned NULL, else return lineRead
}
```

Note that you can also change the return value of readLine to return integer (0 for success, anything else is failure). You need to change your code to check for error accordingly.